# Windows Memory mapping | Bytes change when mapped

Tags: c, windows, memory, mapping

I started a few weeks ago with learning about PE-structure and memorymapping of pe.
I think understand now the basics of this concept.

But then i realized something strange:
When i compared the binary of the file, and the binary mapped into memory (dumped with taskmanager .DMP), i came to the conclusion, that some bytes change after getting mapped into memory.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXE7J.png

In this picture for example (this is an abstract of the start of the .text section of an exampleprogram)
bytes like '0x47' change into '0x43', or '0x40' change into '0x44'

i could not read any patter out of that, or make it senseful in any way.

So i wonder if someone can make a sense out of it, or can help me finding the pattern of the bytes changeing or tell me the reason for that strange behaviour.

(PS: i didnt marked all of the changing bytes in the picture because that would be quite a work, only a few as an example)

Comment: How exactly was the file loaded into memory in the first place?

Comment: by the "windows-default-loader-thingie" i guess, i just ran the .exe file. Im not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: That's not exactly the same thing as memory mapping the file. The kernel has more work to do, than simply memory mapping the file. You are looking at a "fixed-up" image, that has been made ready for execution within it's allotted virtual memory space. It's a fairly complex process. Search for "Windows Internals", or anything on the Win10 kernel.

Comment: big thanks, i will search it up.